# Node application is waiting for the last 'readable' event from a Stream

Tags: node.js, stream, imagemagick, memorystream

I'm working on a Node.js application which load images from a web service, process thumbnail by using ImageMagick, and save the result back into this web service. The workflow is something like

`[Web Service] ==> HTTP Response Stream ==> ImageMagick ==> HTTP Request Stream ==> [Web Service]`

I'm using Node.js `http` module to retrieve the original image stream and save thumbnail stream, and using `imagemagick-stream` module to generate thumbnail without using any temporary file. Since I also need to send thumbnail length I utilized `memorystream` module to hold the thumbnail in memory. So the workflow changed
`[Web Service] ==> HTTP Response Stream ==> ImageMagick ==> memory stream ==> HTTP Request Stream ==> [Web Service]`

The code worked well in my laptop (Mac) and workstation (Windows), but it doesn't work on the Ubuntu server with a special PNG image. But this image worked well on Mac and windows, and it also worked if I were using ImageMagick command line, so this is not a bad image I think.

The phenomenon was, when processing this image, my application was continued waiting for receive the data from ImageMagick, which means it never fired 'end' or 'error' event.
When I tried on my Mac I can see the ImageMagick emitted 3 'readable' event which means it processed 3 chunks of data. But on Ubuntu it only emitted 2 'readable' event and then my code was stay there.

I'm not sure why this happen? Since the image can be processed on Mac, Windows, and can be processed on Ubuntu from command line, I don't think this is because of the image and ImageMagick. I strong doubt there's something wrong to process the stream but have no idea.

Some pseudo-code below

```
var im = require('imagemagick-stream');
var MemoryStream = require('memorystream');

// define ImageMagick parameters
var thumbnail = im().thumbnail(options.width + '>x' + options.height + '>').quality(options.quality);

// retrieve original image
http.request('my web service', function (res) {
    // generate thumbnail
    res.pipe(thumbnail);

    // pipe the thumbnail into memory stream (paused) in order to retrieve its length
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.pause();
    thumbnail.pipe(ms);
    var length = ms._getQueueSize();

    // save back
    http.request('my web service', length, function (res) {
        // ...
    });
    ms.pipe(req);
    ms.resume();
});
```